# Large SQL Server 2000 database

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

I have a large SQL Server database (1 TB) and I do not have more space, what should I use first to try to decrease the size of the database? Deleting tables will take time, shrink also it will take time? Is there a procedure that would run in the background that helps in decreasing the database size?

Comment: Umm. All operations take time.

Comment: If you can describe the best scenario,what should I start with?should I shrink data first, Reindex tables...?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no process you can run that takes no time to decrease the size - if there was I would imagine the SQL team would have it in place automatically.

You can only generally decrease the database size if you delete records.  After that you have to shrink the database.

I've found one of the less time-consuming ways is to truncate or drop tables, but obviously this is not always possible!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to reduce the size without taking any time is `DROP DATABASE` .... Other than that this is a really broad question.

The best way I can think to do this would be to first backup the data then start deleting old data which may not be needed.

I would say your main problem isnt that you need to shrink the database its that you need to put in a plan for maintainance and growth, if you just compress the data you have now you will end up in this same situation again in the future. Re-Indexing wont really help this situation either.

I would try take some time and do this properly, you want to (if possible) backup and export old data, removing it from your database when it is no longer needed, or if this is not possible increase the size of your database as it seems to have grown past your initial designs.

Also maybe put in place a system where you or someone else monitors the database and its size, it shouldn't get to a situation where you say the database is completely full and you have to implement a solution quickly.

Comment: Thank you, I have 3 big tables, I can either truncate them or drop them?which one is better?deleting records is taking time

Comment: Truncate would be easier is possible since you dont have to drop and recreate the table / keys etc. Just make sure you backup the data first.